# Excel Listbox Hide/Unhide Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ListBox (embedded in a sheet) that (upon clicking a button to refresh as needed) will fill with the names of all the sheets in the workbook. (Each has a checkbox to go with it.)

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    Next

End Sub
```

I have tried some various options, but cant sort out a solution as to how to unhide and hide the sheets if they are checked and unchecked, respectively. (And to check/uncheck them if a user manually unhides or hides sheets the old fashioned way.)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is your `ListBix1` on a `UserForm` or embedded on a sheet?

Comment: Embedded in a sheet.

Comment: I am open to making it in a floating userform as well, if you have any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    Me.ListBox1.Clear

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Worksheets(i).Name

        If Worksheets(i).Visible Then
           Me.ListBox1.Selected(i - 1) = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = True
        Else
            Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

- `CommandButtton1` click will populate listbox with sheet names and checkbox
- `ListBox1_Change` will hide/unhide sheets as per checkbox value

Comment: Hey Alex, one last question. The screen seems to flicker, even if I add in some screenupdating = false... do you know why that might be?

Comment: `Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    ScreenUpdating = False
    EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ScreenUpdating = False
            EnableEvents = False
            Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = True
        Else
            ScreenUpdating = False
            EnableEvents = False
            Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
    
    ScreenUpdating = True
    EnableEvents = True

End Sub`

Comment: Nevermind! My brain isnt with me. Needed "Application." before the ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents. Thanks again Alex!!